# Import CSV column from different file into new file

Tags: csv, merge, diff

I have 2 CSV files almost identical with the following differences:

1. The first has a column, "date".
2. The second doesn't have "date" and also has 50 rows less than the 1st ("email").

They are a list of subscribers with date created. The second, however, is the updated list with subscribers who wanted to be removed, but this no longer has the date created.

Is there any way to import column "date" from 1st CSV into the 2nd CSV by making a reference to the "email" column so I can get the correct date of that subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there seems to be not a ready made (probably an evening's worth of effort) command line tool available.

You could look at different ways, one complex way is to load it in tables, to the merge (using a select and join on the two tables) and export it back as csv.

The simplest I could think of was to use [`R`](http://www.r-project.org/) (given that you have header names, in your CSV?):

```
csv1_data <- read.csv('/path/to/csv1.csv')
csv2_data <- read.csv('/path/to/csv2.csv')

merged_csv <- merge(csv1_data, csv2_data)
write.table(merged_csv,file="/path/to/merged_csv.csv",sep=",",row.names=T)
```

The first 2 lines load the data in R, the 3 line [merges](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) them using the default S3 method, the final line exports the result as a csv file, with the headers.

Hope this helps!